# Retornar dados de um Json onde existe uma chave específica em uma variável PHP

Tags: php, json, array

Tenho um `JSON` com uma estrutura padrão.
Dentro da estrutura eu tenho o `codTipo` que vareia entre **A** e **B**

```
{
    "codSeq": "001224",
    "codTipo": "A",

} {
    "codSeq": "001244",
    "codTipo": "A",

} {
    "codSeq": "023444",
    "codTipo": "B",

} {
    "codSeq": "0012444",
    "codTipo": "A",

}
```

Gostaria de saber se tem como eu passar um parâmetro ex: `"codTipo": "B"`, e o `JSON` que for retornado para mim seja somente com os dados do tipo **B**.

```
{
        "codSeq": "023444",
        "codTipo": "B",

}
```

Hoje estou usando o seguinte código para me retornar esses dados:

```
$jsonAcademy = json_encode($jsonAcademy, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

echo $jsonAcademy;
```

Comment: Você fala em passar isso no url e já vir te retornado esse valor ou depois de você capturar o json com o php você passar somente essa chave e retornar os dados de codTipo B?

Comment: Quero apenas passar a chave em php mesmo. esse Json não é tratado por url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trabalhando somente com o objeto JSON e PHP direto, sem convertê-lo para array, um exemplo de como você pode fazer é:

(explico no código o passo-a-passo)

```
<?php
// String JSON
$str_json = '[{"codSeq": "001224","codTipo": "A"},{"codSeq": "001244","codTipo": "A"}, {"codSeq": "023444","codTipo": "B"}, {"codSeq": "0012444","codTipo": "A"}]';
// Analisa a string codificada JSON e converte-a em uma variável do PHP.
$obj = json_decode($str_json);

// Função que recebe como parâmetro a $codTipo e a variável php com a string JSON
function getCodigosPorTipo($codTipo, $obj){
    // Separa com o explode e list a chave 'codTipo' do valor do tipo 'A' ou 'B'
    list($index, $tipo) = explode(":", $codTipo);
    // Remove aspas das variáveis $index e $tipo
    $trimIndex = trim($index, ' " ');
    $index = $trimIndex;
    $trimTipo = trim($tipo, ' " ');
    $tipo = $trimTipo;

    echo "Dados de tipo de código: $tipo<br>";
    foreach ($obj as $index => $dados) {
        // Se o coTipo for igual ao tipo desejado ele imprime as informações
        if ($dados->codTipo === $tipo){
        echo "<br>";
        echo "CodTipo: " . $dados->codTipo . "<br>";
        echo "CodSeq: " . $dados->codSeq . "<br>";
        }
    }
}

// Podemos definir a busca por codTipo A ou B
$busca_por_codTipo = '"codTipo": "B"';
// Chamamos a função 'getCodigosPorTipo' passando os parâmetros necessários para busca e exibição do resultado
getCodigosPorTipo($busca_por_codTipo, $obj);
```

Ao executar o código irá exibir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Convertendo a string JSON para array, é mais fácil de se trabalhar, assim deixo este outro exemplo de código:

(Fiz o código sem função mesmo para realizar o proposto, mas você pode criar uma função similar ao do primeiro código que postei)

```
<?php
// String JSON
$str_json = '[{"codSeq": "001224","codTipo": "A"},{"codSeq": "001244","codTipo": "A"}, {"codSeq": "023444","codTipo": "B"}, {"codSeq": "0012444","codTipo": "A"}]';
// Converte a string codificada JSON para um array do PHP.
$array_codigos = json_decode($str_json, TRUE);

echo "Dados de tipo de código: B <br><br>";

    foreach ($array_codigos as $index => $dados) {
        // Remove aspas da chave codTipo e armaze numa variável $tipo para comparação
        $tipo = trim($dados['codTipo'], ' " ');
        // Se tipo for igual ao tipo desejado, no caso 'B', ele imprime as informações
        if ($tipo === 'B'){
        echo "CodTipo: " . $dados['codTipo'] . "<br>";
        echo "CodSeq: " . $dados['codSeq'] . "<br>";
        }
    }
```

Irá imprimir o mesmo resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo. As duas soluções funcionaram!
Deus te abençoe!

Comment: Tmj meu camarada. 'Deus te abençoe': Amém, Deus te abençoe também! Bora ficar bão na programação! =)

Comment: kkkk... estou nessa luta para me aperfeiçoar mais a cada dia... de vez em quando as coisas travam ai tenho que recorrer aos experts kkk

Comment: Tá certo eu migrei tem pouco tempo para programação também (5 meses de estágio + 6 meses de contratado), mas esta dando pra ajudar no que posso e aprender aqui na comunidade tbm.

Answer (score 2):

caso tu tenha esses dados antes do json, ou usando json decode isso virá um array, desta maneira tu pode fazer um foreach, e ir comparando com o conteudo até achar o codigo que tu quer. 
no momento que tu achar o codigo que tu quer tu separa e coloca em outro array e da json encode.

```
foreach($jsonAcademy as  $i){
    if(strcmp($i['0'],""codTipo": "B"")==0){
      $arraynovo['0'] = $i['0'];
      $arraynovo['1']= $i['1'];
    }
}
```